# Restler 3, php, verbs. How work path?

Tags: post, path, restler

I have a problem. 
How work path in Restler 3?

```
class eventos {
function index($desde=0, $hasta=0) {}

function get($num, $p2='optional') {
       if($p2 != 'attend'){}
       else{}
    }

function post($num, $p2, $request_data = null){

       if($p2 == 'comment'){}
       if($p2 == 'attend'){}

    }
```

}

I need:

GET ...public/index.php/eventos/  (with 2 parameters)  Ok!

POST ...public/index.php/eventos/  (4-5 parameters) **How does it work?**

GET ...public/index.php/eventos/{id}  ok!

GET ...public/index.php/eventos/{id}/attend  **NO WORK!!! work if ...eventos/x?p2=attend, but I do not want this, i want ...eventos/x/attend**

POST ...public/index.php/eventos/{id}/attend  ( X parameters) ok!

POST ...public/index.php/eventos/{id}/comment  (with 2 parameters) ok!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that by "2 parameters", you mean query string parameters)

For Restler 3, parameters that are part of the path (such as eventos /**x** /**attend**) are required. Anything that you want to be optional would have come from the query string.

Since you have designated GET's $p2 to be optional, it can only come from the query string: eventos/x?p2=attend.

If you want to override this and go back to the Rester 2 method, you can turn off this auto-routing as specified here: http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_006_routing/readme.html

As for your POST question about the 4-5 parameters, if you want them required:

```
function post($id, $p1, $p1, $p3, $p4){
```

...or if they are optional:

```
function post($id, $p2, $request_data = null){
```

and then pass the 4-5 parameters in the POST body to the URL eventos/attend or eventos/comment.